# Apache kafka cluster using MapR Spark streaming not working

Tags: apache-kafka, spark-streaming, mapr

We are facing a issue while connecting to Apache kafka cluster using MapR Spark streaming (1.6.1). The setup details are as below:

•   MapR cluster with Spark 1.6.1 (3 node cluster)

•   Apache Kafka cluster v0.8.1.1 (5 node cluster)

We are using ‘spark-streaming-kafka’ library from mapr v1.6.1-ampr-1605. We also tried to run in local mode with apache spark (not mapr spark) this is working very well.

Below is the stack trace of the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: No bootstrap urls given in bootstrap.servers
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.parseAndValidateAddresses(ClientUtils.java:57)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.initializeConsumer(KafkaConsumer.java:606)
        at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(KafkaConsumer.java:1563)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$getPartitions$1$$anonfun$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$getPartitions$1$$anonfun$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:54)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set1.foreach(Set.scala:74)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:251)
        at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:105)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$getPartitions$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaCluster$$anonfun$getPartitions$1.apply(KafkaCluster.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaCluster.withConsumer(KafkaCluster.scala:164)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaCluster.getPartitions(KafkaCluster.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaUtils$.getFromOffsets(KafkaUtils.scala:421)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:292)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaUtils$.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala:397)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09.KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(KafkaUtils.scala)
        at com.cisco.it.log.KafkaDirectStreamin2.main(KafkaDirectStreamin2.java:111)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:742)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

PS: we are passing “metadata.broker.list” while creating connection.
Spark streaming application is not able to connect to ZK and not able to get bootstrap URL. This is what my understanding. Or it could be issue of not having correct version of map-r and kafka jar.   We took jar from Map-r side but still not working.

We are able to test with apache spark successfully but not able to get it working on mapr.

Any help appericated.

Answer (score 0):

In your stacktrace there are references to `org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.v09` which probably means that it's an implementation using the new consumer API which became available with Kafka 0.9 and won't work with Kafka 0.8.1.1. You should probably try one of the libraries from [MapR's spark-streaming-kafka_2.10](http://repository.mapr.com/nexus/content/groups/mapr-public/org/apache/spark/spark-streaming-kafka_2.10/) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But it is not helping. We are still debugging the issue.